# Background Image not appearing on Blog page in Wordpress 4.75

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Can anybody tell me how the feature images appear on Blog page. I have embedded my blog in index.php and have gone through various forums but could not make the image to appear. I am using the below code-

```
<div id="main" >


<section class="feature-image feature-image-default-alt" >
    <h1 class="page-title">Blog</h1>
</section>

    <!-- BLOG CONTENT
================================================== -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="primary">

        <main id="content" class="col-sm-8" role="main">

            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :

                if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
                    <header>
                        <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header>

                <?php
                endif;

                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;

                the_posts_navigation();

            else :

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

            endif; ?>

        </main><!--content-->

        <!-- SIDEBAR
        ================================================== -->
        <aside class="col-sm-4 asidebar">
                <?php get_sidebar();?>
            </aside>

    </div><!--primary-->
</div><!--container-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a function for that:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();

    echo '<img src="'.$featured_img_url.'">';
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Comment: Hi @user8242904, glad it worked. Could you accept the answer as correct?